# C# webservice call not called from ajax

Tags: c#, ajax

my .aspx page has a javascript ajax call to the .cs webservice written in the same project under App_Code folder. There are many ajax webservice calls that get called but when I added a new webservicve method and tried to call from javascript, it doesn't get fired. I put a break point in the new webservice call but the visual studio (community edition 2013) does not stop or not get there. Any common/generic reason(s) for this behavior?

Comment: This question might end up being closed because it doesn't meet SO guidelines. Here's their guidance, which might help you improve it: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> Please share your code or use below code..

```
 <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
  $("[id*=submitbtn]").click(function () {
    var username = $.trim($("[id*=txtUserName]").val());
    var userage = $.trim($("[id*=txtUserAge]").val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service.asmx/GetUserDetails",
        data: "{ username: '" + username + "', userage: " + userage + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (r) {
            alert(r.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```